# Laravel Hash::make Hash::check works randomly

Tags: php, laravel, hash

I'm generating password hashes and updating my user's row but I have to change the password two or three times to get authentication working.

I have this code to generate hashes

```
    //Make hash 
    $hashed = Hash::make($pin);
```

For some technical reasons I'm returning this hash to other windows program and doing update of the user's password in that program. Saving user in Laravel makes no difference with my problem. And also checked hundred of times that stored hash in database is exactly the same as the generated password in Laravel all the times (working cases and not working cases).

Later in my LoginController I'm doing this:

```
 $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required'],
        'password' => ['required'],
    ]);
$user = User::where('usu_per_login', $credentials['email'])->first();
Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->usu_per_pin)
```

As I said Hash::check will return false many times but not always. For example:
-I establish password to 12345
-I try to login with 12345 and Hash::Check returns false
-I establish password again to 12345
-I try to login with 12345 and Hash::Check returns again false
-I establish for third time password to 12345
-I try to login with 12345 and Hash::Check returns true.

After working once will work forever until I change password again. I've been trying a lot and sometimes only I need two password changes to work, sometimes three, sometimes four and sometimes I cannot make work with certain passwords.

I've read all posts about authentication with laravel but not found any with this randomly malfunction.

Could you please give me some tip to solve this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: you can eliminate a lot of supposition with `Hash::check($credentials['password'], Hash::make('12345'))` wich will return always true. then you have an error in your pipeline (creating hash, sending to tiers program, saving to DB) which you have no details/debug info about in your question. maybe some encoding went wrong

Comment: thanks for your answer, it helped me to think and finally I got a version that it works but I dont really understand was really failing.